# mysql union query with individual alias on each union

Tags: mysql, union, alias

Am creating a search query mysql, using `UNION` to join multiple tables, now my problem is to add alias to identify each table, because if i add table name with alias it will show error `COLUMN NOT FOUND` Am trying to add alias on each union table but am getting errors which i don't know what to do to get it write can anyone help.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (
        SELECT 'food' as type,
        food_id AS item_id,
        food_name AS item_name,
        primary_image AS item_img,
        food_price AS item_price,
        food_currency AS item_currency,
        food_discount AS item_discount,
        chef_status AS ison
        FROM foods
    ) AS f

    UNION

    (
        SELECT 'chef' as type,
        chef_pagename AS item_id,
        business_name AS item_name,
        chef_photo AS item_img,
        NULL AS item_price,
        NULL AS item_currency,
        NULL AS item_discount,
        chef_status AS ison
        FROM our_chefs
    ) AS c
) AS fsc

WHERE f.food_name LIKE '%chicken%'
OR f.item_price LIKE '%100%'
OR c.business_name LIKE '%chicken%'
AND fsc.ison = 1
```

Thank you guys for contribution, i got solved the problem now by doing the

```
WHERE item_name LIKE '%chicken%'
OR item_price LIKE '%100%'
AND fsc.ison = 1
```

Comment: you can place your filters in each query separately. What else do you need them for?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM (

  (
    SELECT 'food' as type,
    food_id AS item_id,
    food_name AS item_name,
    primary_image AS item_img,
    food_price AS item_price,
    food_currency AS item_currency,
    food_discount AS item_discount,
    chef_status AS ison
    FROM foods
    WHERE food_name LIKE '%chicken%'
    OR item_price LIKE '%100%'
  )  

  UNION

  (
    SELECT 'chef' as type,
    chef_pagename AS item_id,
    business_name AS item_name,
    chef_photo AS item_img,
    NULL AS item_price,
    NULL AS item_currency,
    NULL AS item_discount,
    chef_status AS ison
    FROM our_chefs
    WHERE business_name LIKE '%chicken%'
  )  
) AS a

WHERE  a.ison = 1
```

Comment: I know i can do it this way, but i have a php search controller that does advance filter for me. So i will need those alias to pass the table name

Comment: I don't know php but can you use the type column? that what's usually done to be able to identify from which query it was returned.

Comment: or maybe your question is really a php question.

Comment: No, i don't think is php question, because running that query alone still will give error. So does it mean i can't do it similar like my question?

Comment: your query is wrong because the outer query see's both unions as 1 table that has whatever was returned from both queries. not 2 separate tables.